# Jquery autocomplete not working - No search result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am creating inside an ajax call a country list which is an array of objects:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + zipCode + '&region=AT',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (res){
        var countryList = [];

        ... ...
        ... ...

        countryList.push({
            label: countryCode + ' ' + countryName,
            value: result[0]['id'],
            countryId: result[0]['id'],
            countryCode: countryCode,
            countryName: countryName,
            city: city
        });

        zipCodeSelector.autocomplete({
            source: countryList
        });

    }

})
```

The response of the automcomplete is

> No search results

The Object looks like this:

```
[Object]
0: Object
    city: "Berlin"
    countryCode: "DE"
    countryId: "a7c40f631fc920687.20179984"
    countryName: "Germany"
    label: "DE Germany"
    value: "a7c40f631fc920687.20179984"
```

I call the autocomplete function inside the ajax. Is that a problem or is there something else?

Comment: I am not sure if it is a typo or not, but you are missing `'` at the end of the ajax url.

Comment: You should move the autocomplete call inside of the ajax call's `success()` function.

Comment: yes it is like that was a copy paste issue... I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You can call your ajax method inside the source option instead of populate prior an array.

The [`source`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) option accept a custom function see:

> Function: The third variation, a callback, provides the most
>   flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to
>   Autocomplete. The callback gets two arguments: A request object, with
>   a single term property, which refers to the value currently in the
>   text input. For example, if the user enters "new yo" in a city field,
>   the Autocomplete term will equal "new yo". A response callback, which
>   expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data
>   should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of
>   the formats described above for simple local data. It's important when
>   providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the
>   request. You must always call the response callback even if you
>   encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the
>   correct state. When filtering data locally, you can make use of the
>   built-in $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex function. It'll take a single
>   string argument and escape all regex characters, making the result
>   safe to pass to new RegExp().

Code:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: function (req, resp) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=55.397563, 10.39870099999996&sensor=false',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (res) {
                resp($.map(res.results, function (item) {

                    return {
                        label: item.formatted_address,
                        value: item.place_id
                    };
                }));
            }

        })
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vzhjstuf/

Answer (score 0):

Try to access your `JSON` content like this because you specify on  `ajax` call to expect data in `JSON` format on res.

To access a property of your `JSON` do following and then push it to another array.

```
res[0].city;
res[0].countryCode;
```

Access property of an object rule is:

```
Object.property
```

Comment: I don't know if this is an issue since the object is ok. It has the same structure like here http://jsfiddle.net/kcTR2/ and this one works...